# Should I convert two AC units to a dual-zoned unit?

Tags: zoned-heating

One-story 2200 square ft home, currently with two AC units, need replacing, which is better two AC units or a dual zoned hvac system?

Comment: What kind of AC units?

Comment: Are you looking at variable air volume (damper) zoning, or variable refrigerant flow/volume zoning (i.e. a "multi-split" system with a mini-split type outdoor unit and multiple indoor heads)?

Comment: There are reasons _to_ do it and reasons _not to_ do it. Whether you _should_ or not is your opinion, based on the facts you gather and which ones are most applicable to you. Unfortunately, opinion based questions are off topic here.

Comment: Thanks for responses. It is two 3 ton units, 2232 sq ft house. One reason to convert would be to save money on the cost of replacing two units. Not sure how many HVAC companies are familiar with it, and would only want to split for two zones in the house obviously controlled by the two thermostats that are already there.

Comment: Are your existing systems failing? Is there duct work existing that could tie the zones together? If no ductwork mini splits may be a better option possibly keep 2 main outdoor units with inside units in the rooms only heat the rooms you use , use the existing power. The question s really a broad one with many possibilities and it would be opinion based in most cases.